# Setting height to 100vh works but i get a scroll bar in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a centered login screen. This is centered in all browsers perfectly but when I open it on my android phone the page gets a scroll bar, I think this is because of the navigation menu on my mobile browser which disappears when I scroll down on a web page.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.centered_layout {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered_layout">
    Centered app
</div>
```

Comment: Does your page have this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes its in my <head>

Comment: Can't saw that issues in your snippet

Comment: @JoshuaJenkins can you show the code for your navigation menu?

Comment: It's because of the address bar in android chrome. try to use `overflow: hidden` for body.

Comment: @KhalilLaleh This works but then the app is not centered anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: New solution

```css
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.centered_layout{
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    overflow: auto;

    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered_layout">
    Centered app
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution! I love that we can stick to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

found this solution:

```
body {
min-height: 100vh;
/* mobile viewport bug fix */
min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

here's a link to article:
https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

Answer (score 0):

There are two different solutions for this.

1. Using Dynamic viewport (`dvh`) units:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.centered_layout {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100dvh;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered_layout">
    Centered app
</div>
```

But if you use this unit, you may notice a small flicker or glitch.

2. Using Small viewport (`svh`) units:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.centered_layout {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100svh;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered_layout">
    Centered app
</div>
```

There's no issue I've found while using this one.

> Note: These two units might not work on/support older browsers.